# My php code won't connect to my database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

here is my code :

```
<?php
$servername = "XXXXXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXX";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

and here is the error 
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'rgwyatt_loganf'@'192.185.46.82' (using password: YES) in /home4/rgwyatt/public_html/loganf/test.php on line 14
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'rgwyatt_loganf'@'192.185.46.82' (using password: YES)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, it will be your MySQL configuration, which may only be granting access from specific hosts, can you mange your own MySQL users?

Comment: No that is managed by someone else, but i will talk to him about it.

Comment: MySQL Credentials are often _User + Pass + Connection Source_

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a permissions problem. Double check that the ip, user name and password (if required) are correct. If you are trying to connect from a different ip, maybe you don't have permission for your ip.

Also notice that the error you have posted gives away the ip user name and password.

And if you are trying to connect to a specific DB, then you are missing the db parameter.

It should be like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($servename,$username,$password,$db);
```

Comment: It's actually optional. The db argument is only required if querying a database table. One can still successfully connect without it. One would get something back like this: *"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <path to file> on line x"*. This when using that function to query with as an example.

Comment: Tnx for your comment. You are correct. I edited the response already.